# Can't manage to make jquery.transit to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition, hammer.js

I'm trying to combine Hammer.js and jquery.transit to create a nice drag effect on a side menu, but, I can't manage to make jquery.transit to work (yep, that sounds stupid... ).

Here is what I have

```
var $mainPage = $('#main-page');
  var drawer = 0;
  if(Modernizr.touch){
    $mainPage.hammer()
              .on('swiperight', function(e){
                if(drawer){
                  return true;
                }
                $mainPage.transition({ x: 260 });
                drawer = 1;
              })
              .on('swipeleft', function(e){
                if(!drawer){
                  return true;
                }
                $mainPage.transition({ x: 0 });
                drawer = 0;
              });
```

But, I keep getting the `Object [object Object] has no method 'transition'`... Any idea why ?

Answer (score 0):

Please look at the following example and note the `prevent_default: true` option passed to `hammer.js` in order to run smoothly on devices. Regarding your error i guess you did not use the jquery plugin of hammer.js , since it working fine in the example below.

### http://jsbin.com/ExECiHUS/1/edit

**html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset=utf-8 />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.7.1/modernizr.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/jquery.transit.min.js"></script>
  
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/hammer.js/1.0.6/jquery.hammer.js"></script>

<title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  <div id="main-page" style="background-color:grey;height:100px;">this is main page</div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**js**

```
var $mainPage = $('#main-page');
  var drawer = 0;
  //if(Modernizr.touch){
    console.log($mainPage);
$mainPage.hammer({prevent_default: true})
              .on('swiperight', function(e){
                console.log('swipe right');
                if(drawer){
                  return true;
                }
                                            console.log('transition');
                $mainPage.transition({ x: 260 });
                drawer = 1;
              })
              .on('swipeleft', function(e){
                console.log('swipe left');
                if(!drawer){
                  return true;
                }
                $mainPage.transition({ x: 0 });
                drawer = 0;
              });
  //}else{
    //console.log('touch events not supported!');
  //}
```

Comment: I can't explain it... I have almost exactly have the same code, but I keep getting the same error and nothing moves...

Comment: @Axiol can you please place your code online e.g jsfiddle,jsbin, so i can take a look? thanks

Comment: It's a whole WP project, but I'll look to do it during the day. But, the only difference I can see is that on my project, Modernizr is load at the top of the page and everything else is compress in one file at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Axiol place an output to the console like `console.log($mainPage);` as shown on the example, to check if jQuery works as it should and the element has been selected. Also this code should follow the inclusion of the libraries, in order for `jQuery`, `hammerjs` and `jquery.transition` to be available.

Comment: @Axiol also check the version of jquery you are actually using by entering `console.log(jQuery().jquery);` within the code above.